# Write concurrently in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concurrency, parallel-processing

I have a task to do on a lot of line of data (in a `pandas` `DataFrame`), but each computation is independent, thus I would like to parallelize it.

So I have a function taking a row and outputting an object (the ouput is actually an array containing a string and a set).

```
def compute_row(index, row, output):      
    output[index] = some_function(row)
```

And then I try to use it in parallel.

```
output = np.empty(data_length, dtype=object)

num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(compute_row)(i, row, outputx) for i, row in db.iterrows())
```

The problem is that I get back an array of `None`, even if I replace `some_function` by `1` for example.

Since the indexes are unique, there should not be any concurrent memory access issue. What am I missing here? Should I use another data structure maybe?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The output is an array of `None` because the method `compute_row` is supposed to return something. Why don't you just `return some_function(row)`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, 
I found another way, using a `Pool` object.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def compute_row(row):    
    return some_function(row)

pool = Pool()
output = pool.map(compute_row, (row for i, row in db.iterrows()))
```